# Is this function BV or not?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a really stupid question about $BV$ functions, I hope somebody can confirm/destroy my opinion!
Consider the set $\Omega:=[-1,1]\times [0,1] = A \cup B \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, where $A:=[-1,0]\times [0,1], B:=(0, 1]\times [0,1]$, $f, g \in \mathscr{C}^1(\overline{\Omega})$ and define $u:=\begin{cases}f&\text{on }A,\\ g&\text{on }B\end{cases}$. Using the definition of total variation, one can see easily (at least seems to me...) that $u$ is a $BV(\Omega)$ function. But, on the other hand, the distributional derivative of $u$ is "easily checked" to be (at least, seems to me...)
$$
 D_iu = -(f+g)\mathscr{H}^1|\Gamma + \partial_if \mathscr{L}^2|A + \partial_i g\mathscr{L}^2|B,
$$
where $\Gamma:=\left\{0\right\}\times [0,1]$ (and "|" should be replaced by "\lefthalfcup", but does not seem to work here!).

Now, seems a little bit weird to me that this measure is actually a (signed) Radon measure, but I cannot prove or disprove this. So, what is happening? Or better, am I wrong in saying this function is BV or am I wrong saying $Du$ is not (signed) Radon (yes, in every case seems I am wrong somewhere... :) )? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This function is in BV, but its distributional derivative isn't quite right. I'd say it is 
$$D_1 u = (g-f)\mathscr{H}^1|\Gamma + \partial_1 f \mathscr{L}^2|A + \partial_1 g\mathscr{L}^2|B$$
$$D_2 u = \partial_2 f \mathscr{L}^2|A + \partial_2 g\mathscr{L}^2|B$$
because the derivative in second coordinate is not affected by the discontinuity across $\Gamma$.

Note that the above does not take into account the boundary of $\Omega$, i.e., derivative is taken considering $\Omega $ to be the domain. If the function is extended by $0$ outside of $\Omega$, there will be additional terms coming from $\partial \Omega$.

> Now, seems a little bit weird to me that this measure is actually a (signed) Radon measure

Yes, it is a signed Radon measure. What is weird? Given any continuous function $\varphi\in C(\overline \Omega)$, you can make sense out of its integral with respect to the measure $D_i u$.