# What does the symbol ∟ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, notation, distribution-theory, radon-nikodym

I encountered this symbol $\lefthalfcup$ ∟ in the statement of Besicovitch derivation theorem. It says that the Radon-Nykodym decomposition of the given measure $\nu$ is $\nu=f\mu+\nu^s$, $\nu^s$ is singular with respect to $\mu$ and

$$
\nu^s∟ E
$$

where $E$ is a specific set.

I don't understand what that symbol means. It also appears in Federer-Vol'pert theorem and it may have something to do with distributional derivatives as seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/759687/570189), but I really can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Screenshot of page 24 of [The Comprehensive $\LaTeX$ symbol list](https://people.math.osu.edu/snapp.14/immerse/symbolList.pdf):

[image: ![as described above]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Source: [Functions of Bounded Variation and Free Discontinuity Problems](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=7GUMIh6-5TYC&dq=Functions+of+bounded+variation+and+free+discontinuity+problems&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSj7megrDgAhW5FLkGHc83B40Q6AEIKTAA) by Luigi Ambrosio, Nicola Fusco, Diego Pallara.